# are there piano pieces where the hands play in different keys?

Tags: composition, harmony, composers

Do you know music for piano where the two hands don't have to play in the same key?

Comment: I've heard people play that way, but don't think it was written as such...

Comment: I was tempted to add a trivia tag, since I can recognize no practical impact of the question, but there seems to be none.

Comment: @guidot I think a question asking about the existence of polytonality is a little more than "trivia", considering it has sparked an entire movement of contemporary composing...

Comment: @TreFox: I would agree more, if the question contained at least a hint of a level beyond trivia. Note that it is a closed question, where a simple *yes* would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

The term for such music is *[polytonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytonality)*.

Keep in mind that polytonality may not necessarily apply to the *entire* composition. It would not be un-common for a composition to have *only parts* which are polytonal.

Many polytonal works will be from the early 20th century. You will see some of the composer names in the wiki article: Stravinsky, Bartok, Milhaud, Ives, etc.

Here is one the cited examples from Milhaud: [Copacabana](https://youtu.be/zZanU1ZaN6k?t=5m30s). Right hand is in `B` major and the left hand is `G` major.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Each part separately is pretty clear and simple (diatonic within their respective tonalities.)
- The listener should be able to *hear* each part is in a separate key. From examples I have seen, that separation is largely contingent on the clarity of the separate parts. You should need to strain to hear the two keys.
- Some counterpoint/rhythmic contrast between parts will help with perceiving the separation.
- A large tonal contrast help with separation. The difference between `G` (one sharp) and `B` (5 sharps) is 4 accidentals. That's a pretty large contrast of tones. It's hard for `G` to be confused with `B`. But, compare `C` and `F` major. The difference is only 1 flat. When combining those two keys the results could sound like extended harmonies of 9th or 11th chords, or perhaps a `C` tonic with a variable natural `^7` or `b^7` scale degree. A similar point could be made about blues tonality. It isn't polytonal, it's a idiomatic blending of major and minor and 'blue' notes, but clearly there is only *one* tonic.

That's probably the essential point with polytonality: you really need to hear *two* (or more?) simultaneous tonics.

Comment: There is polytonality (or maybe polymodality according to you reference) even in popular music. This song was a summer hit here in Brazil last year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYxcW8jtFw0. Melody is in Ab major, and harmony in Ab minor.

Comment: FWIW, I have sometimes played with taking a given piece of music - like a classical piece with simple alberti bass or a familiar song like Jingle Bells - and just transpose one of the hands to hear a "polytonal" rendition. Kinda silly, kinda fun.

Comment: @coconochao - modal mixture is a little semantic as far as polytonality is concerned.

Comment: At sound checks, I like to play 'The Entertainer' r.h. in original C, l.h. in C#. It works - in a weird way. And if anyone comments, I ask if the piano's been tuned lately..!

Comment: Do you know the story about Charles Ives' father who was a band leader? He would have two marching bands play in different keys. Apparently an influence on the son's crazy music.

Comment: @michael: no, never heard about this. do you know which march it was?

Comment: I don't recall if a specific tune was mentioned. Scan this page for 'polytonality' http://www.ryangarber.com/ives.html, it has the type anecdotes I recall.

Answer (score 5):

Bela Bartok Mikrokosmos Vol. IV

99)   cm / am

101)  am / Ebm

103)  B  / am

105)  em / c#m (both pentatonic)

There are some others: It's obvious that two hands play in different keys, even it is not signed as such.

But the title will say it clear.

Answer (score 4):

Surprised that there's been no mention of the Blues, where often the left hand (accompaniment) is played in a major key, while the right hand is played, in a fashion, in the parallel minor, more or less, with the addition of a tritonal b5, putting it into maybe an unknown key.

Comment: I just made an edit to my post, re. blues. In the strict academic sense it's not polytonal. There aren't two tonics simultaneously.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - OP's question asks - different keys.

Comment: up vote for mentioning the blues!
I always thought improvising in G above E or C above A was my invention ;)